# Right or wrong: $f$ has antiderivative for $r<|z|<R\iff\exists \rho \in (r,R)$ such that $\int_{K_\rho(z_0)}f(z)dz=0?$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In the following question, $K_{\rho}(z_0)$ is the circle with radius $\rho$ around $z_0$.

> Right or wrong: $f$ has antiderivative for $r<|z|<R\iff\exists \rho \in (r,R)$ such that $\int_{K_\rho(z_0)}f(z)dz=0?$

My intuitiion thought this has to be wrong, since the general Cauchy integral formula does need a simply connected domain which this isn't. But I can't seem to find a counterexample.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Do you assume $f$ is analytic in the domain?

Comment: @GBA yes! I‘ll put it in on there.